# Moving larger numbers to right, and smaller numbers to left of given value

Tags: java

I have a homework problem that gives me this array:

[3, 22, 1, 5, 6, 10, 4]

And I need to move all numbers that are larger than the last value, 4, to the right of the value and all of the values that are smaller to the left.

The numbers do not necessarily need to be in order. So, the output of the program would be:

[3, 1, 4, 22, 5, 6, 10]

For some reason I am really struggling to think of an algorithm that would allow for this to happen. I have tried creating a loop that swaps the last value with larger numbers, but if a smallest value is mixed in the array somewhere odd it will be to the right of the value which is not correct.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do it have to be in place? i.e. is there a constraint to only use the array the one array?

Comment: @Jesse yes there should only be one array. And it should not be sorted before rearranging the array.

Comment: This is classic QuickSort algorithm. However, you are expected to keep pivot at 4 and do the first iteration. You stop once you are ready to change the pivot.

Comment: And hint: if you just do a normal full sort of the whole array, you get to your target condition as well.

Comment: @GhostCat It would, but the instructions did not allow for a normal selection or binary sort to happen, so The Roy is correct that I just need to handle the first pivot of a Quick Sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't help you complete the home-work. But I will guide you to think where this example of yours is headed. It is the first step of quick sort - Partitioning the array.

```
public class QuickSortImpl {

    private static void swap(int[] array, int l, int h) {
        int temp = array[h];
        array[h] = array[l];
        array[l] = temp;
    }

    public static int partition(int[] array, int low, int high) {
        int pivot = high;
        int firsthigh = low;
        int x,y;

        for (int i = low; i < high; i++) {
            x = array[i];
            y = array[pivot];
            if (array[i] < array[pivot]) {
                swap(array, i, firsthigh);
                firsthigh++;
            }
        }
        swap(array, pivot, firsthigh);
        return firsthigh;
    }

    private static void printArray(int[] arr ) {
        for ( int i =0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
            System.out.print(" " + arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void quickSort(int[] array, int low, int high) {
        if ( low < high ) {
            int pivot = partition(array, low, high);
            quickSort(array, low, pivot - 1);
            quickSort(array, pivot + 1, high); 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 3, 22, 1, 5, 6, 10, 4};
        quickSort(arr, 0, arr.length -1 );
        printArray(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This wasn't actually a homework problem, it was a test question that stumped me today. We have not learned about the quick sort algorithm yet so I was surprised we were expected to know this. This is definitely the right answer though.

Comment: @brent_mb, For a start I would consider implementing custom comparator, a lot easier, cleaner and to your level appropriate, but this is a good example too.

Answer (score 0):

@brent_mb, take a look at this simple example for your cause:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] listOfNumbers = {1,4,5,6,74,2,7,8,5,2,6,989,3};
        //sort by number 6
        FirstCustomComparator comparator = new FirstCustomComparator(6);

        Arrays.sort(listOfNumbers, 0, listOfNumbers.length, comparator);

        for (int number : listOfNumbers) {
            System.out.print(number+" ");
        }
    }
```

> FirstCustomComparator class:

```
public class FirstCustomComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {

    private final int exception;

    public FirstCustomComparator(int i)
    {
        exception = i;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b)
    {
        if (a < exception)
        {
                return -1;

        }
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```